# Set transform origin property X and Y coordinates

Tags: javascript

[Set transform origin property X and Y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655896/set-transform-origin-property-x-and-y-coordinatesIm) struggling to set transform origin property from javascript for both axis.

so from javascript: `object.style.transformOrigin = valueX valueY;`

Unfortunately, it doesnt work... if i set 2 values it doesnt work.. if i set only 1 value, the valueX is changed only.

What i have done:

```
newClasses.style.transformOrigin = scaleOrigPoint + "px"; // sets only for valueX
newClasses.style.transformOrigin = (scaleOrigPoint + "px") + (scaleOrigPointY + "px"); // sets only for valueY
newClasses.style.transformOrigin = (scaleOrigPoint + "px") , (scaleOrigPointY + "px"); // doesnt set anything + ERROR
newClasses.style.transformOrigin = (scaleOrigPoint + "px") (scaleOrigPointY + "px"); // doesnt set anything + ERROR
newClasses.style.transformOrigin = [scaleOrigPoint]px; // doesnt set anything + ERROR
```

And many many other ways... Somethimes it changes the valueY only...

**Question:**

Is there a way to set bot valueX and valueY for transform origin property using **javascript only**?

Comment: Style properties set in JavaScript should be strings, as if written in a CSS stylesheet after the `<property>:`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried putting a space between them?

```
newClasses.style.transformOrigin = scaleOrigPoint + "px " + scaleOrigPointY + "px";
```

Comment: You were right... its ok now! Thanks alot m8. Accept in 7 mins